# Typings project and use of Definitely Typed Repository

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript-typings

How to add typings from definitely typed repository in my Angular 2 project, and how these files (i.e `*d.ts`) will be mapped to corresponding JavaScript library?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is just to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).

On your second question: if you setup typings correctly, the compiler will find the proper module automatically, no need for any triple-dash references anymore .

Comment: Please note that this answer is obsolete. Search the web for modern approaches to handling TS typings.